# Count the number of vowels,pronouns in each line of string?

Tags: ruby

I need to count the number of vowels,words,pronouns("he,she,them") in each line of a string entered by user. if input is "they are playing. he is studying" the output expected is Sentence 1 has 3 words,has 4 vowels , 1 pronoun. \nSentence 2 has 3 words,4 vowels , 1 pronoun.  I have written the following code but getting an error unexpected-end-of-input.

```
string = gets
string =string.chomp


sentencecount = 0
wordcount = 0
pronouns={"He"=>0,"She"=>0,"They"=>0,"Them"=>0}
procount=0;
string.split(".").each do |sentence|
  wordcount = 0
  sentencecount += 1     #tracking number of sentences
   vowels=sentence.scan(/[aeoui]/).count
   procount=0
  sentence.split(/\w+/).each do |word|
    pronouns.each do|key,value|
        if (key.eq word)
            procount++

    wordcount += 1  # tracking number of words
  end

  puts "Sentence #{sentencecount} has #{wordcount} words, has  #{vowels} vowels"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

- you don't need semicolon at the end of the lines
- `if` requires an `end` (unless it's the inline form)
- `++` operator doesn't exist in Ruby
- you compare two strings with the `==` operator (it's a method actually)

  ```
  string = gets.chomp

  sentencecount = 0
  wordcount = 0
  pronouns = {"He"=>0, "She"=>0, "They"=>0, "Them"=>0}
  procount = 0
  string.split(".").each do |sentence|
    wordcount = 0
    sentencecount += 1     #tracking number of sentences
    vowels = sentence.scan(/[aeoui]/).count
    procount = 0
    sentence.split(/\w+/).each do |word|
      pronouns.each do|key, value|
        if key == word
          procount += 1
        end
        wordcount += 1  # tracking number of words
      end
    end

    puts "Sentence #{sentencecount} has #{wordcount} words, has  #{vowels} vowels"
  end
  ```

Comment: it is giving 0 as pronoun everytime i run

Comment: after giving procount+=1 also it is not updating..can you please tell me how to update

Comment: make two things: this `sentence.split(/\w+/).each do |word|` become `sentence.split.each do |word|` and this `if key == word` become `if key.downcase == word.downcase`

Answer (score 0):

Based off of your initial attempt, I've optimized it slightly and make it more readable in terms of code.

```
string = gets.chomp
pronouns = ['he', 'she', 'they', 'them']
total_word_count = 0
total_procount = 0
total_vowel_count = 0

sentences = string.split(".")
total_sentence_count = sentences.size

sentences.each_with_index do |sentence, idx|
  # VOWELS
  vowel_count = sentence.scan(/[aeoui]/).count
  total_vowel_count += vowel_count

  # WORDS
  words = sentence.split
  sentence_word_count = words.size
  total_word_count += sentence_word_count

  # PRONOUNS
  sentence_procount = 0
  words.each do |word|
    sentence_procount += 1 if pronouns.include?(word.downcase)
  end

  total_procount += sentence_procount

  puts "Sentence #{idx + 1} has #{sentence_word_count} words, has  #{vowel_count} vowels"
end

puts "Input has #{total_sentence_count} sentences, #{total_word_count} words, #{total_vowel_count} vowels, and #{total_procount} pronouns"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you return an array of hashes, one for each line, each hash containing statistics for the associated line. You can then do what you want with the information in that array.

```
VOWELS   = 'aeiou'
PRONOUNS = %w| he she they them |
  #=> ["he", "she", "they", "them"] 
PRONOUN_REGEX = /\b#{Regexp.union(PRONOUNS)}\b/
  #=> /\b(?-mix:he|she|they|them)\b/

def count_em(str)
  str.downcase.split(/\n/).map { |line|
    { vowels:   line.count(VOWELS),
      words:    line.scan(/[[:lower:]]+/).count,
      pronouns: line.scan(PRONOUN_REGEX).size } }
end

a = count_em "He thought that she thought that he did not know the truth\n" +
             "René knew she would torment them until they went bananas\n"
  #=> [{:vowels=>14, :words=>12, :pronouns=>3},
  #    {:vowels=>15, :words=>10, :pronouns=>3}] 

a.each.with_index(1) { |h,i|
  puts "In line #{i} there are %d vowels, %d words and %d pronouns" %
    h.values_at(:vowels, :words, :pronouns) }
  # In line 1 there are 14 vowels, 12 words and 3 pronouns
  # In line 2 there are 15 vowels, 10 words and 3 pronouns

puts "The total number of vowels in all lines is %d" %
  a.map { |h| h[:vowels] }.reduce(:+)
  # The total number of vowels in all lines is 29
```

This solution is incomplete in that it doesn't deal with contractions ("don't"), possessives ("Mary's"), abbreviations ("1st"), initials and numeric parts of names ("J. Philip ('Phil') Sousa III") and other twists of the English language.